# Should I flag a post as spam after it had already been closed it with the "other" reason?

Tags: support, flags, vote-to-close, spam

A user [posted a spam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27665430/remove-spam-attempt). [paxdiablo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27665430/remove-spam-attempt#comment43746176_27665430) closed it with the "other" reason stating that

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about spam

I also did the same. Now,I saw that one can flag a post as spam. Should I flag the post with

> It is spam.
>   This question is effectively an advertisement with no disclosure. It is not useful or relevant, but promotional.

or should I leave it as it is as I've already closed it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that post should have been flagged as spam, and should **not** have been edited.

Spam flags feed back into the automated system to help block such posts. By not flagging you deprive the system of valuable training input.

Comment: As soon as I flagged it,It was deleted. BTW,is there a link stating when to flag and when to close or something like that?

Comment: @CoolGuy: [What are the spam and offensive flags, and how do they work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Do you know whether flagging for closure has any effect on spam-flags, like disputing them? Or how and why my spam-flag might have gotten disputed there?

Comment: My,my! Just look at the [spam that the same user has in his "About Me" section](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4397413/jamie-quinones)!

Comment: @Deduplicator: sorry, I don't know. The post did not receive enough community spam flags to even be auto-redacted, I see.